# Using scanner to find the end of a line?

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I am scanning text into a program using the scanner class, 
and each line of the text file is a booking of the form

```
(id) (month) (date) (numdays) (type1) (number1) (type2) (number2) . . .
```

The first four elements of the booking data are always the 
same number i.e. 4, but the (type) and (number) data could have 
any number of arguments, hence I want to detect the end of a line
is there any way to do this with the scanner class?

I want to find the end of a line so my code doesn't read the 
next line a continuation of a booking.

} else if(input.equals("Booking")) {

```
                int bookingId=inputStream.nextInt();
                System.out.printf("%d ",bookingId);
                String month = inputStream.next();
                System.out.printf("%s ", month);
                int date = inputStream.nextInt();
                System.out.printf("%d ", date);
                int numDays= inputStream.nextInt();
                System.out.printf("%d ", numDays);


                while(!(inputStream.findInLine("\n").equals("\n"))){
                   String nextType = inputStream.next();
                   System.out.printf("%s ",nextType);
                   int nextCapacity= inputStream.nextInt();
                   System.out.printf("%d ", nextCapacity);
                   Map<String, Integer> requests=new HashMap<String, Integer>(); 
                   requests.put(nextType,nextCapacity); 

                }
```

Comment: Ya.. `Scanner.next()` has an overloaded method that takes a `pattern` as an argument. If you show us your input, we could show you the right direction :)

Comment: Also, What is it that you want exactly?.. Why do you want the end of line?..

Comment: Maybe you're looking for a while loop.

Answer (score 0):

you can either check for EOL :

```
charAt(i)!='\n' && charAt(i+1)!='\r'
```

or you may just read the whole line at a time :

```
 Scanner sc = new Scanner(file);

 line = sc.nextLine();
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your code I suggest using two scanners: one for reading whole lines and one for reading symbols in line. This way first scanner will take care about EOL. The code would look like this:

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File("input"));

while(sc.hasNextLine()) {
    Scanner scLine = new Scanner(sc.nextLine());

    int bookingId=scLine.nextInt();
    String month = scLine.next();
    int date = scLine.nextInt();
    int numDays= scLine.nextInt();

    System.out.printf("%d %s %d %d ", bookingId, month, date, numDays);

    Map<String, Integer> requests=new HashMap<>();
    while(scLine.hasNext()) {
        String type = scLine.next();
        int capacity= scLine.nextInt();
        requests.put(type, capacity);

        System.out.printf("%s %d", type, capacity);
    }

    System.out.println();
}
```

Comment: Thanks very much my parser is doing its job quite well now, However I am getting a error message "Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException" Do you have to close a scanner or some such ?

Comment: No. The problem is most likely in you input file. You try to read element when it isn't there. Either a line is less than 4 symbols like `(id) (month) (date)` or you have unpaired type and number like `(id) (month) (date) (numdays) (type1) (number1) (type2)`

Comment: I can get all the cases to read correctly and then print them out for the input file, thats why i thought it might be something to do with getting to the end of an input file?